# Pepper Robot Wheel Control

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

Is there a way to control the individual wheels of the Pepper in a fashion similar to how you can control the legs of the NAO?

We would like to use our own motion controller for the base of the robot, but it seems that any commands send to the wheel via DCM are automatically overwritten by ALMotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that setting stiffness via DCM is not possible if you provide the value in the form of an integer. For example:

```py
service.setAlias(['WheelStiffness', 'Merge', 'time-mixed', [
    [[ 1, service.getTime(0) ]],
    [[ 1, service.getTime(0) ]],
    [[ 1, service.getTime(0) ]],
]])
```

Does not work, where-as the following does:

```py
service.setAlias(['WheelStiffness', 'Merge', 'time-mixed', [
    [[ 1.0, service.getTime(0) ]],
    [[ 1.0, service.getTime(0) ]],
    [[ 1.0, service.getTime(0) ]],
]])
```